# ¿Por qué me repite los valores del select?

Tags: php, mysql

Muy buenas tardes, tengo una consulta, el problema que tengo es que al momento de "modificar" mi registro, en mi select me muestran todos los nombres de las universidades que fueron registrados en los usuarios.

Por ejemplo si hubo dos usuarios registrados con universidad "undc", entonces en mi select al modificar me salen esos dos, cuando solo deben aparecer uno.

Tenía el problema que no me mostraba el seleccionado en mi select al momento de modificar, lo solucioné, pero ahora mi select se muestra así:

```
<select class="chosen-select" name="uni_cod" data-placeholder="-- Seleccionar Universidad --" autocomplete="off" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php

                  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,  "SELECT p.part_dni, u.uni_cod, u.uni_nombre FROM participantes p
                                                   INNER JOIN universidades u
                                                   ON p.uni_cod = u.uni_cod
                                                   ORDER BY u.uni_nombre ASC")
                                                   or die('error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    echo "<option "; if($row['part_dni']==$_GET['id']) echo "selected"; echo " value=\"$row[uni_cod]\"> $row[uni_nombre] </option>";
                  }
                ?>
</select>
```

Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Más adelante piensa en mejorar tu estilo de programación. Esto: `echo "<option "; if($row['part_dni']==$_GET['id']) echo "selected"; echo " value=\"$row[uni_cod]\"> $row[uni_nombre] </option>";` es ilegible como código, hace daño a la vista. Es sólo una crítica constructiva. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo un inner join entre la tabla de participantes y la de universidades, tu consulta te está sacando tantas tuplas como usuarios haya cruzada con la universidad q él usuario a registrado. Y tú recorres dichas universidades, deberías de realizar una consulta nada más de la tabla de universidades, para sacar las tuplas de dicha tabla sin tener en cuenta los participantes

Comment: Pero como haria para obtener el valor seleccionado en mi select del registro guardado

Comment: Por lo q parece tu ya has cargado los datos del usuario en otra consulta anterior, tan solo tiene que cruzar los datos en el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Para que sólo te saque una tupla por universidad necesitas agrupar los resultados en la query por nombre o id de universidad.

```
SELECT p.part_dni, u.uni_cod, u.uni_nombre 
  FROM participantes p
  INNER JOIN universidades u ON p.uni_cod = u.uni_cod 
  GROUP BY u.uni_nombre
  ORDER BY u.uni_nombre ASC
```

**Edición**

Para mostrar todas las universidades y si algún participante las ha seleccionado tomas cómo tabla principal universidades y haces un `LEFT JOIN` a participantes

```
SELECT p.part_dni, u.uni_cod, u.uni_nombre 
      FROM universidades u participantes p
      LEFT JOIN participantes p ON p.uni_cod = u.uni_cod 
      GROUP BY u.uni_cod
      ORDER BY u.uni_nombre ASC
```

Comment: Oh! muchisimas gracias, me habia olvidado del GROUP BY, yo estaba intentando con el DISTINCT pero no sabia como implmentarlo, se lo agradezco.

Comment: No hay de que, con esto debería funcionar. Si la consideras respondida márcala como tal.

Comment: Hola Carmen, como seria en el caso de querer que me muestre todas las universidades que se registro en mi tabla? en vez que me aparezcan la universidades que se registro en los usuarios?

Comment: En ese caso en lugar de INNER JOIN haces un LEFT JOIN declaración tabla universidades a la tarde tabla participantes. Ahora lo edito.

Answer (score 0):

Tu query no está filtrando por usuario, así que es normal que te devuelva todas las relaciones existentes entre universidades y participantes.

Deberías modificar tu query para agregar una cláusula WHERE y filtrar por el id del usuario que te interesa

```
SELECT p.part_dni, u.uni_cod, u.uni_nombre 
FROM 
  participantes p INNER JOIN universidades u ON p.uni_cod = u.uni_cod
WHERE p.part_dni = el_dni_de_tu_usuario
ORDER BY u.uni_nombre ASC
```

De esta manera obtendrás todas las universidades en las que ha participado **un determinado usuario** (el que busques)

Comment: Hola Julio, pero lo que quisiera es que me muestre todas las universidades de mi tabla, solo me muestras las universidades que se registro con los usuarios, mas no las otras universidades de la tabla

Comment: Entonces consulta únicamente la tabla de universidades como sugiere la respuesta de Manuel.